# replace all but certain html tags with htmlspecialchars() in PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-entities, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

I would like to process my user input to allow only certain html tags, and replace the other ones by their html entities, as well as replace non-tag-characters. For example, if I only wanted to allow the `<b>` and the `<a>` tag, then

```
allow_only("This is <b>bold</b> and this is <i>italic</i>.
            Moreover 2<3 and <a href='google.com'>this is a link</a>.","<b><a>");
```

should produce

```
This is <b>bold</b> and this is &lt;i&gt;italic&lt;/i&gt;.
Moreover 2&lt;3 and <a href='google.com'>this is a link</a>.
```

How can I do this in PHP? I am aware of `strip_tags()` that can **remove** the unwanted tags completely, and I'm aware of `htmlspecialchars()` which can replace **all tags** by their html entities, but none where only specific tags get replaced. How can this be done in PHP?

And if there is no 'common' way to do this, how should I in general go on processing user input that can have valid regular html, but can also have `<` signs and potentially dangerous html code?

Comment: I think a series of regular expressions to either match or replace the HTML attributes would work better in this scenario. As it'll give you 1) A new programmatic approach to solutions and 2) allow you the freedom to control your user inputs and restrict/allow HTML attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply htmlspecialchars and then replace encoded entities with regular entities for a given array of tags

```
function allow_only($str, $allowed){
    $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
    foreach( $allowed as $a ){
        $str = str_replace("&lt;".$a."&gt;", "<".$a.">", $str);
        $str = str_replace("&lt;/".$a."&gt;", "</".$a.">", $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
echo allow_only("This is <b>bold</b> and this is <i>italic</i>.", array("b"));
```

That works for simple tags, returning  "This is **bold** and this is <i>italic</i>."

As it was pointed out, that doesn't work for tags with attributes, but this does:

```
function fix_attributes($match){
    // TODO: study $match[2] in depth and avoid banned attributes
    // eg: those that begin with on, or href that begins with javascript:
    // to avoid some potential hacks
    return "<".$match[1].str_replace('&quot;','"',$match[2]).">";
}
function allow_only($str, $allowed){
    $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
    foreach( $allowed as $a ){
        $str = preg_replace_callback("/&lt;(".$a."){1}([\s\/\.\w=&;:#]*?)&gt;/", fix_attributes, $str);
        $str = str_replace("&lt;/".$a."&gt;", "</".$a.">", $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
echo allow_only('This is <b>bold</b> and <a href="http://www.#links">this</a> is <i>italic</i>.', array("b","a"));
```

that handles more complex tags with certain attributes, only the characters listed between `[]` are allowed to appear in attributes by this.  Unfortunately `&quot;` must be allowed within attributes or it won't work, and with it all other entities are allowed too - however only `&quot` in attributes will be decoded.

As it was suggested a much better (safer, cleaner) way to solve problems like this to use a library like http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php

Comment: Maybe for making this answer full you can add useful php library htmlpurifier.

Comment: Hmm, but that doesn't seem to take care of the tag's arguments, for example allowing `<a>` will not allow `<a href="mysite.com">` to survive the cleansing (while for `strip_tags()` it would).

Comment: Not filtering for attributes is very unsafe here. If this is user supplied data, this code allows for JS injection with inputs like `<a onclick="eviljs();">Get hacked</a>`.