# How can I only render certain html tags for my forum?

Tags: javascript, php, html, htmlspecialchars

I am currently building a forum and am trying to print out posts with formatting (bold, italicized, images, etc.) The user inputs the text using http://summernote.org/ My php code is currently set to:

```
echo nl2br(e($content));
```

Which prints out: (printing the actual tags)

```
<p><b>asdffddd d d d d </b></p>
```

When I surround my echo function with htmlspecialchars_decode, it renders every single html tag. This is obviously not ideal, because users could put things like iframe's or div's and break the layout of my page.

What would be the best way to only render the following tags

```
<b>
<i>
<u>
<p>
<h1-6>
<img>
<a>
<span>
<ul>
<ol>
<li>
```

I would still like it to display non-allowed tags in text form, just not render them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223295/replace-all-but-certain-html-tags-with-htmlspecialchars-in-php might be of use.

Comment: What about using regular expression for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip_tags` to achieve this.

```
<?php
$html = 'Your html';
$allowableTags = '<a><b>'; // add allowable tags
echo strip_tags($html,$allowableTags);
?>
```

I hope this helps.