# How to use htmlspecialchars() but keep the <a> tag along with others in PHP?

Tags: php, xss, sanitization, htmlspecialchars, html-sanitizing

I am trying to use htmlspecialchars() but want to preserve the following tags:

`<a>`, `<b>` and `<i>`.

How would I go about doing so?

The solutions that I have found do not seem to work together with an attribute tag and a normal plain tag.

Here is a piece of code that I have found that is supposed to allow for tags with attributes:

```
function fix_attributes($match){
    return "<".$match[1].str_replace('&quot;','"',$match[2]).">";
}
function allow_only($str, $allowed){
    $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
    foreach( $allowed as $a ){
        $str = preg_replace_callback("/&lt;(".$a."){1}([\s\/\.\w=&;:#]*?)&gt;/", fix_attributes, $str);
        $str = str_replace("&lt;/".$a."&gt;", "</".$a.">", $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
echo allow_only('This is <b>bold</b> and <a href="http://www.#links">this</a> is <i>italic</i>.', array("b","a","i"));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223295/replace-all-but-certain-html-tags-with-htmlspecialchars-in-php)

However, it keeps giving me an error: **Use of undefined constant fix_attributes**

I would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: use `strip_tags()` instead if you want to retain certain tags.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner while this is a good general solution, it's worth noting that `strip_tags()` does have a host of problems and can often give bad returns (garbled code). Some form of (very complex) regex would probably work but that's a big answer......

Comment: If you want to use a named callback in `preg_replace_callback` you have to pass the function name as a string; i.e. `'fix_attributes'`. That should fix your error message. But I can't tell you if the regex is save/good.

Comment: @jh1711 Thanks! However it doesn't seem to allow `<?` as an input and results in a Forbidden 'error'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** use callback function without quotes

for more info see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

```
 <?php
    function fix_attributes($match){
        return "<".$match[1].str_replace('&quot;','"',$match[2]).">";
    }
    function allow_only($str, $allowed){
        $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
        foreach( $allowed as $a ){
            $str = preg_replace_callback("/&lt;(".$a."){1}([\s\/\.\w=&;:#]*?)&gt;/", "fix_attributes", $str);//use quotes here 
            $str = str_replace("&lt;/".$a."&gt;", "</".$a.">", $str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    echo allow_only('This is <b>bold</b> and <a href="http://www.#links">this</a> is <i>italic</i>.', array("b","a","i"));
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works but doesn't seem to allow `<?` like `htmlspecialchars()` normally takes in and sanitises. Having that as an input results in a Forbidden error.

Comment: Managed to fix that, I had to disable `Mod_Security`